# Unable to install codelite on deepin 15.5

Tags: linux, c++, ide, deepin

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 codelite : Depends: libclang1-3.4 (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 but it is not installable
            Depends: liblldb-3.6 but it is not installable
            Depends: libssh-4 (>= 0.6.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: xterm but it is not installable
            Depends: libclang1 but it is not installable
            Depends: clang-format-3.4 but it is not installable or
                     clang-format-3.5 but it is not installable
            Recommends: gdb but it is not installable
            Recommends: lldb (>= 3.4) but it is not installable
            Recommends: nodejs but it is not installable
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Have you tried to fix the broken packages? How and with what result?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: On ubuntu all needed files downloaded and install automatically, but i think deepin is a pain in the ass.

Comment: I tried install GCC with build essential am getting this error: E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate

Comment: Try, AS ROOT: apt -get install -f            What happens?

Comment: I tried su but i was unable to login, i got authorization problem.

I used sudo -i to login as root but i still get same error.